# What gap should I set my mill's rollers to?

Tags: mill, grain, all-grain, crush

I just received a Barley Crusher mill - is the default roller setting sufficient for most grain types, or do I need to worry about adjusting it?

Do you guys change roller spacing based on what grain you mill (i.e. barley vs wheat) or just keep it the same and crush away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default should be fine for most all applications. I have heard of people driving the wheat through twice, without going through the exercise of changing the mill regularly.  Not because its hard but because sometimes you forget and next time you screw up your crush.

Comment: Thanks, would like to avoid changing it all the time, and the double-milling of some grain like wheat sounds like a good workaround! Means I don't have to go buy feeler gauges either!

Comment: What good are feeler gauges anyway.  When I mill I push a pound through and look at it and I adjust as I go.  Grain can vary a bit seasonally and by humidity levels really.  You just go by feel and make it tighter or looser.  Buying feeler gauges just allow you to put a # on it, but you still got to look at the grain and pick tighter or looser.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what the gap on my mill is set to, and I don't really care.  Learn what a good crush looks like and how it acts in the mash tun, and settings won't matter to you.  Not to mention, a setting that works with one person's system might not work for another's.  Keep in mind that you're making grist, not gaps!  The finer you mill your grain, the higher your efficiency will be.  I advise you to keep reducing the gap slightly every time you brew.  If you have runoff problems open it back up a bit next time.  Take a good look at your grist at that point and you'll know what you;re looking for from then on.